# Why doesn't this coffee-script print out?

Tags: coffeescript

So when the index is 0, I want to print it out:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ] 

for i of a
    if i == 0
        console.log a[i]
```

But there is no output.

`i == 0` is never true...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i returns the index as a string, if you parse them as an integer, it would work

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ] 

for i of a
    if parseInt(i) == 0
        console.log a[i]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! I just figured it out by myself minutes ago... LOL Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ZhangXiao But kurmiau's answer was posted before yours. So, I suggest to delete your own answer, and accepts this one.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `i` will only be 1, 2 or 3, as you loop over the items in `a`, not the index numbers.

This works the way you described above:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ] 

for i in [0..a.length]
    if i == 0
        console.log a[i]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer :)
However I was looping on the index. Notice that I was using `of` but `in`.

Comment: @ZhangXiao: You shouldn't use `of` to loop over an array, use `in` to loop over arrays.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. I understand the difference and in this case I use `of` :)

Comment: @muistooshort Oh... I didn't realize that. Could you explain why? In this case, what I am doing is to iterate an array and for the first element I want to do something special.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `of` to loop over an array, you should use `in`. From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> Comprehensions can also be used to iterate over the keys and values in an object. Use `of` to signal comprehension over the properties of an object instead of the values in an array.
>
> ```
> yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11
>
> ages = for child, age of yearsOld
>   "#{child} is #{age}"
> ```

So you're trying to iterate over the *properties* of an array object, not its indexes.

You should use one of these for your loop:

```
for e, i in a
    if(i == 0)
        console.log(a[i])

for e, i in a 
    console.log(e) if(i == 0)

console.log(e) for e, i in a when i == 0

#...
```

Or, since you have an array and a numeric index, why not just skip the loop and get right to the point:

```
console.log(a[0])
```